# Kernel debugging between two virtual machines not working

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, kernel-mode, virtual-machines

i want to do kernel debugging on my vm from another vm.

My setup is pretty simple,

**Debugged - VM**:
Windows XP SP3 x32 (To be debugged)

**Debugger - VM**: 
Windows 7 SP1 x64 (With Windbg installed - the Debugger)

the pipe configuration is pretty simple as well..
both ends should be set as `The other end is a virtual machine`, and on the XP VM i set the pipe as `This end is the server` and on the Win7 vm i set `This end is the client`. Im using **Vmware Workstation 10.0.3** btw..

I know i did setup my XP vm correctly because i can debug it from the host easily - configuring `The other end is an application` and connecting it with Windbg from my host computer (Win7 x64) and its working properly. So i know there is no problem with my Win-XP setup

But doing the same thing from the other vm, nothing happens. I looked through the internet and i even followed tutorials that explained exactly what i already did.
I have no idea what i'm missing and i feel pretty helpless so i came asking here.

Anyone got any ideas what is the problem with my setup?

Comment: Are all your settings the same as described in http://www.ndis.com/ndis-debugging/virtual/vmwaresetup.htm ?

Comment: @JasonGeffner, It does look a little different than my setup, yet its still not working. The difference is (Between what i thought is correct): They put on the Debugged vm `The other end is an application` when the other side is a VM that is supposed to debug it. 

Also on the windbg, the pipe name they use is `\\.\com1` instead of `\\.\pipe\com_1` which is what i did. Nonetheless its still not working even with their setup

Comment: As per http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/topic/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-44A7A5CC-0292-4AEC-A500-812850F8C040.html, are you sure the serial port is connected in both VMs?

Comment: And if that isn't the problem, you may want to ask on https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/workstation/content

Comment: @JasonGeffner, i dont see any unique explanation on that link you sent me. But under the configuration settings in both VMs. the serial port on both is on `connected state` and both has the same `Pipe Name` of `\\.\pipe\com_1`

Comment: Sorry, link should have been http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-143ACB87-9439-4702-A928-455A36BD7EC9.html

Comment: @JasonGeffner, yes they are both connected

Comment: @JasonGeffner, https://communities.vmware.com/message/2557171#2557171
I gave it a try.. lets see if ill get any luck there

Comment: Since you are using VMWare Workstation, I would recommend the use of [VirtualKD](http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/). It is really easy to set up, and is extremely fast.

Comment: @tmr232, Thanks you very much for the option, but right now im just trying to generally kernel-debug and not interested at the moment in improving any speed. But i will look into it in the future if ill be able to get it done

Comment: I understand. In my experience it is a lot easier to set it up, compared to the vm-to-vm debugging.

Comment: @tmr232, I dont understand.. isnt your method just an improvement to a vm-to-vm debugging? as in to make it faster?

Comment: No. It is host-to-vm debugging. After installation, it usually works out of the box.

Comment: Well thanks but this is not what i need, and my host to vm already works with no problem

Comment: VirtualKD is practially abandoned, but there's a fork VirtualKD-Redux someplace on Github. Also note that for many operations the speed is more than sufficient. But there are plenty of scenarios where you with to have a faster connection (such as Firewire in the past) and then the VirtuakKD method is very handy (driver development is sped up by transferring new builds over the KD connection during boot). Also keep in mind that Windows since 8.1 should support KD over network. Although I never tested it with VMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem.. 
On the windbg client, uncheck the 'Reconnect' and 'Pipe' checkboxes on the COM tab - then it will connect to the debugger.